# Multiple of identity plus compact

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is there an example of a bounded operator $T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$, where $H$ is a separable complex Hilbert space,  such that no restriction to an infinite dimensional closed subspace is multiple of identity plus compact?

Edit: What I mean by "restriction" is $T_{|M}:M\to H$, where $M$ is an infinite dimensional subspace of $H$, and by "multiple of identity" I mean a complex multiple of the inclusion map $i:M\to H$.

Comment: Do you want to consider only restrictions to *invariant* and *closed* subspaces?

Comment: Closed yes, invariant no.

Comment: If $T-I$ is an isometry, then its restriction to any infinite dimensional subspace is not  compact since the image of the non-compact unit sphere in this subspace can not be sent to a compact by an isometry, right?

Comment: The shift is certainly an example, since (using the von Neumann-Wold decomposition) it can be proved that every restriction of the shift to a closed invariant subspace is unitarily equivalent to the shift. 

Could you clarify what you mean by "restriction" if the subspace is not invariant?

Comment: @MikeJury Added what I mean by restriction, hopefully it is clear now (and it makes sense).

Comment: @S.carmeli  $T-\lambda I$ will not be an isometry for all $\lambda$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I think it turns out that the shift $S$ is *not* an example in this case, since I think it's possible to construct co-invariant subspaces $M$ of the shift that are almost invariant for $S$ (that is, $SM\ominus M$ is one-dimensional) and the compression $P_MS|_M$ is of the form $I+K$, but I will need to check the details.

Comment: @user129564 you are correct of course, sorry!

Comment: Possibly this can be extended to proving that no normal bounded operator is an example?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answers. I only realized at the end that I misunderstood what was meant by "multiple of identity".

Comment: A normal operator cannot give such an example because (Weyl-von Neumann) a suitable compact perturbation will give it pure point spectrum, and then there will in fact be a reducing subspace $M$ on which $T-c$ is compact for any $c\in\sigma_{ess}(T)$ (which can't be empty since $T$ is bounded).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, let me try too. It is going to be a somewhat long story. WLOG, $\|T\|\le 1$.

**Step 1:** It is enough to show that for every finite-dimensional subspace $E$ and every $\delta>0$, there exists a unit vector $v\in E^\perp$ and $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $\|Tv-zv\|\le\delta$.

**Proof:** Suppose that the claim holds. Choose a square summable sequence $\delta_j>0$. Construct by induction a sequence of pairwise orthogonal unit vectors $v_j$ and numbers $z_j$ such that $\|Tv_j-z_jv_j\|\le\delta_j$. Passing to a subsequence, we can ensure that $z_j\to z$ and, moreover, $\sum_j|z_j-z|^2<+\infty$. Then $T-zI$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator on $\operatorname{span}(v_j)$.

**Step 2:** Suppose that $1>\delta>0$ and $a_j$ is a sufficiently long (i.e., of length $\ge N(\delta)$) sequence of positive numbers such that $\delta^2 a_j\le a_{j+1}\le a_j$. Then there exist $m<n$ such that if we multiply $a_j$ by an (automatically non-decreasing) geometric progression so that the resulting products $a_j'$ will satisfy $a_m'=a'_n=1$, then we shall have $\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} a_k'\ge \delta^{-2}$.

**Proof:** Consider the points $P_k=(k,\log a_k)$, $k=0,\dots,N$ and take the convex hull of rays going from those points up. It will be bounded by two vertical rays and several slanted intervals. Now, if there is a slanted interval between $P_m$ and $P_n$ with $n-m>\delta^{-2}$, we are done (because for the corresponding modified sequence $a_k'$, we'll have $a_k'\ge 1$ for $m\le k\le n$). Otherwise, since the slopes of slanted intervals are squeezed between $2\log\delta$ and $0$ and increasing, we can find $2\delta^{-2}$ subsequent intervals that form an almost straight piece, provided that $N$ is large enough. Then if $P_m$ is the left endpoint of the left of those intervals and $P_n$ is the right endpoint of the right of those intervals, we have $n-m\ge 2\delta^{-2}$ and $a_k'\ge\frac 12$ for $k$ between $m$ and $n$.

**Step 3:** Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional subspace. Let $\delta>0$ and let $N$ be large enough to guarantee the conclusion of Step 2. The conditions $x,Tx,T^2x,\dots, T^Nx\in E^\perp$ define a closed subspace of finite codimension in our infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$. Let $x$ be a unit vector in that subspace. Consider the sequence $x_k=T^kx$, $k=0,\dots, N$ and the numbers $a_k=\|x_k\|^2$. If we have $a_{j+1}<\delta^2a_j$, then the normalized vector $x_j$ is what we are looking for with $z=0$. Otherwise choose $m<n$ as in Step 2. Let $q^2\ge 1$ be the ratio of the corresponding geometric progression and $r^2$ be its $m$-th term. Then for the vectors $y_k=rq^{k-m}x_k$, we have $\|y_m\|=\|y_n\|=1$ and $y_{k+1}=qTy_k$. Let $|\zeta|=1$. Consider the vector
$$
y=y_\zeta=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\zeta^{-k}y_k.
$$ 
Then $\|Ty-\zeta q^{-1}y\|=\frac 1q\|\zeta^{-n}y_n-\zeta^{-m}y_m\|\le 2$. However, the average  of $\|y_\zeta\|^2$ is $\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\|y_k\|^2\ge \delta^{-2}$, so we can use the normalized $y_\zeta$ with appropriately chosen $\zeta$  (with $2\delta$ instead of $\delta$).

It is the last step that uses the Hilbert space structure in a really essential way (though the previous steps made some limited use of it too), which makes me wonder  what happens in an arbitrary Banach space.

Comment: This is really nice.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you. I figured it out when finally realized that the eigenvector approach seems to lead nowhere because for the backward shift in $\ell^2(n^{-2})$, say, all eigenvectors have a huge projection to the first coordinate vector. So the next question was what vectors would work for that case and the answer was $(0,\dots,0,1,\dots, 1,0,\dots)$. The rest was just an attempt to generalize this construction.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is essentially Theorem 3.1 in:

A. Brown, C. Pearcy, *Compact restrictions of operators*, Acta. Sci. Math (32) 1971, 271-282 ([link](http://pub.acta.hu/acta/showCustomerArticle.action?id=8286&dataObjectType=article&returnAction=showCustomerVolume&sessionDataSetId=28bc5047da2446b0&style=))

In fact, something a bit stronger and in more generality is true (see Proposition 3.2 in [this](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022123613001183/1-s2.0-S0022123613001183-main.pdf?_tid=3d2bc0f1-23f8-4fc8-9508-91b317a8a8ea&acdnat=1538797523_7265fe6af133a369474083e9865fec04) paper):

**Proposition:**  Let $X$ is a  Banach space and $T\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ such that there exists $\lambda\in\partial\sigma(T)\setminus\sigma_p(T)$. Then there exists $e\in X$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find $Y$ an infinite dimensional and infinite co-dimensional subspace of $X$ with the property that $(\lambda I-T)_{|Y}:Y\to Y+[e]$, and $(\lambda I-T)_{|Y}$ is compact and has norm less than $\epsilon$.